# Error while importing sbt project , Server Access error, unresolved dependencies

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to import libraries in my project in build.sbt from IntelliJ IDE 15.0.2. I keep getting unresolved dependencies error. I tried to update settings from different forums to resolve it, but none works. Few things I tried:

1. Update sbtconfig.txt with proxy settings,
2. clean up and Invalidate/restart cache from project settings
3. remove .sbt, .ivy2 folders and restart the IDE and launch project. Still no use.

Here is the error I keep getting now:

```
Nbr of module to sort : 0
    resolved ivy file produced in cache
:: downloading artifacts ::
:: resolution report :: resolve 185393ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
WARN:   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
WARN:   :: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found
WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Nbr of module to sort : 0
    report for org.scala-sbt#boot-jansi;1.0 default produced in C:\Users\admin\.sbt\boot\resolution-cache\org.scala-sbt-boot-jansi-default.xml
    resolve done (185393ms resolve - 0ms download)

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\admin\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:


    C:\Users\admin\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\jars\jansi.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

      -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: Connection reset url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

    Server access Error: Connection reset url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

    Server access Error: Connection reset url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
java.lang.RuntimeException: not found
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:238)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:292)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:714)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.getDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:594)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:234)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Update.scala:106)
    at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$4.call(Update.scala:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Update.scala:101)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:352)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$jansiLoader$1.apply(Launch.scala:178)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.jansiLoader$2f324eef(Launch.scala:173)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.<init>(Launch.scala:150)
    at xsbt.boot.Launcher$.apply(Launch.scala:366)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$.error(Pre.scala:26)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Update.scala:106)
    at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$4.call(Update.scala:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Update.scala:101)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:352)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$jansiLoader$1.apply(Launch.scala:178)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.jansiLoader$2f324eef(Launch.scala:173)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.<init>(Launch.scala:150)
    at xsbt.boot.Launcher$.apply(Launch.scala:366)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
```

Comment: Probably just some temporary network problems. The URL works: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom - just retry

Comment: yep the URL work from browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the fix for this issue.. it was my machine trying to connect to ipv4 internet IP via ipv6 TCP/IP stack. I did ran this command to apply the fix to force and use ipv4

`setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to import project (import `build.sbt` file) on machine without Internet.

I had the similar error message:

```
UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES
org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found
```

without any stacktrace in IntelliJIdea window.

Then I created file `repositories` in `[home_dir]/.sbt/` folder with correct list of repositories for me, and it worked.

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html