# sbt 0.13 on Windows - Cannot Access Repositories

Tags: windows, scala, sbt

I've gone through almost everything related to installing sbt on Window on stackoverflow (there are quite a few people having the same problem with me). However, the answer seems unclear/unreproducible on my machine.

Here is what I did:

1. Download sbt-0.13.13 on this [site](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html)
2. Install it successfully and set the PATH
3. Try `sbt version` to see if it is installed successfully. Error
   returned (as at the end of this post)

A few things we should know:

- I already have JDK
- I don't use Proxy on my computer (tested with `netsh winhttp show
  proxy`)
- Someone said it is because sbt doesn't support ASCII character - but
  the solution wasn't clear

  ```
      problems summary
  WARNINGS
      module not found: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11

  local: tried

    C:\Users\buidu\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\ivys\ivy.xml

    -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

    C:\Users\buidu\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\jars\jansi.jar

  ==== Maven Central: tried

    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

    -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

  ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

    https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

  ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

    https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

   UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES

   org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found

  Server access Error: Permission denied: connect url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

  Server access Error: Permission denied: connect url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

  Server access Error: Permission denied: connect url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

  Server access Error: Permission denied: connect url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
  ```

Comment: I have had this error myself, but I was behind a corporate firewall and I needed to provide an in-house substitute for every repository that sbt needs to reach.

Comment: For instance, I cannot even `ping repo1.maven.org`, so I need to define `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dsbt.repository.config="someDir/repositories.sbt"`. Are you runnng from Windows command line, or from a Cygwin bash? Did you try specifying the full path to `sbt.bat`, to make sure you are executing that file?

Comment: I can ping that site, mate. And I also tried the full path to `sbt.bat` but I still received the same error

Comment: You could try to install a Cygwin distibution, e.g. Babun (http://babun.github.io/). It's lightweight and makes more sense as a shell for sbt. That's how I have set up my environment.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to configure the use of IPV4 (not IPV6), as described in the accepted answer for this question:

[Error while importing sbt project , Server Access error, unresolved dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34686953/error-while-importing-sbt-project-server-access-error-unresolved-dependencies)

`setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Comment: Thanks. I saw that thread and tried it but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same for a week. The only thing, that helped, was to uninstall sbt from the default location (c:\Program Files(x86)\sbt) and reinstall it to some location without spaces (I've installed it to d:\sbt).

Comment: No luck for me. I uninstalled and installed it on `C:\sbt` (no space at all). And it still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Did you try taking a look in your sbt repositories file (likely to be c:\users\.sbt\repositories, and specifying http:// instead of https:// ?